# Как отправить 0 преобразовав его к числовому типу?

Tags: javascript

Есть простая форма с проверкой числовых данных через регулярное выражение через такую функцию:

```
function filterFloat (value) {
    var floatTemplate = /^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/;

    if( floatTemplate.test(value) ){
        return Number(value);
    }

  alert ('Неверное значение!');
}
```

При попытке отправить ноль не происходит вообще ничего - как поправить?

Comment: Ваша функция обрабатывает **строку** `0` верно и возвращает **число** ноль. Возможно у вас дальше проверка неправильно построена.

Comment: `filterFloat(0) === 0` - будет `true`. Так что ошибка скорее всего там, где вызывается `filterFloat`.

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что результат проверки присваивался переменной, а переменная равная нулю получался false

Comment: @Leo240 если проблема решена, пожалуйста, напишите ответ самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что результат проверки присваивался переменной, а переменная равная нулю возвращает false.

Решение: добавил в условие проверку на равенство нулю

```
var quantityValue = filterFloat( $('#quantity').val() );

    if(quantityValue || quantityValue === 0){
        //дальнейшие действия
    }
```

Comment: лучше ограничится одной проверкой на `null`/`undefined`: `if(quantityValue != undefined){`